# How to use PHP Sockets?

Tags: php, multithreading, sockets, websocket

What is the use of PHP web sockets based on the client-server model that php uses? I want to set up a chat-room sort of environment where there is a persistent connection between the server and multiple clients, but php's way of handling things does not seem to support such usage. I would assume that I would use sockets and threads, but beyond that I don't know if it is feasible. Would this kind of application work with php, or do I need to consider using a different programming language (perhaps python)?

Thanks

Comment: questions with *"I don't know where to start"* are not a good fit on S.O

Comment: I changed the question. Hopefully it aligns with the practices of StackOverflow questions a little better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/). It runs on top of Symfony, a PHP framework. The tutorial builds a chat room.